# Manipulation many object by one

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I have situation

`<Grid>
  <FlipView x:Name="flip1">
    ...
  </FlipView>
  <FlipView x:Name="flip2">
    ...
  </FlipView>
</Grid>`

How I can synchronize manipulations on these two FlipView controls?
If user makes 'swipe' gest on grid, booth of FlipViews should change page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try binding `SelectedItem` property of these two - e.g. set `SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=flip2, Mode=TwoWay}` on flip1. The results with touch manipulation feedback might not be ideal though and you can't make it perfect even if you try to manually synchronize the offset on the `ScrollViewer` in the template of each of the `FlipViews`.

Comment: But if I binding SelectedItem, then secound flipview selection will be changed after 'selection changed' event from first flipview.

Comment: I was thinking that we can assign all manipulation from one control to another.

Interesting fact. If I add events to booth flipview, SelectionChanged_flip1 and SelectionChanged_flip2, and set flip2 Visibility=Collapsed then booth events (electionChanged_flip1 SelectionChanged_flip2) will be call on swipe gest.

Comment: You can't control manipulation events on `ScrollViewers`. They are manipulated with Direct Manipulation and rendered in a separate Direct Composition surface. You only get access to the `ViewChanged` events when panning happens.